# Folland 2.28 questions about equivalence between Riemann and Lebesgue

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a couple questions regarding Folland’s 2.28 theorem.

1. Why does $g\leq f \leq G$ imply that there exists $h \in L^1$ such that $ |f_n| \leq h$? Would I use $max(g,G)$? If so how do I know this is in $L^1$?
2. Why does $m$ have to be complete as in the last line?
3. Why do I drop the $[a,b]$ on the integral $\int G dm$ in the last line but not on the $\int_{[a,b]}fdm$

[image]

Comment: If $f$ is Riemann integrable on a compact interval, it is bounded by a constant, _a fortiori_ there exists an integrable function $h > 0$ such that $|f| \leq h$ (take $h$ as a constant). $m$ has to be complete since you are only showing $f = G$ up to a Lebesgue null set. Your thid question is just laziness of the author. Folland is a great book once you know but not too good to learn, skips too many details in my opion (just like Rudin's books).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Note that $G_{P_1} \geq G_{P_2} \geq \cdots \geq G,$ since $G_{P_k}$ is always a more refined bound than $G_{P_{k-1}}.$ Also, since $f$ is bounded, say $|f| \leq B$ on $[a, b],$ so that $|G_{P_k}| \leq B$ on $[a, b],$ implying $|G| \leq B$ on $[a, b].$ Thus by dominated convergence (since constant functions are $L^1[a,b]$ because $[a,b]$ has finite measure), we get that $\int G \, dm$ is the limit of $\int G_{P_k} \, dm,$ which of course implies $\int G \, dm = \int_a^b f(x) \ ,dx$ by definition of the Riemann integral. A similar argument works on $g_{P_k}.$
2. This is a little subtle. Take a measure $m$ which is note complete; then there's some measure zero set $A$ with a subset $B \subseteq A$ which is *not* measurable. Then $0 \leq \chi_B \leq \chi_A.$ Despite the fact that $\chi_A = 0$ a.e., and that $\chi_B$ is sandwiched between them, we do not have that $\chi_B$ is measurable! Really, when Folland says $G = f$ a.e. he's using $m$ is complete, since otherwise the set where $G \neq f$ isn't neccessarily measurable. Here, the argument is that since $g \leq f \leq G,$ and since $G - g \neq 0$ on a set $A$ of measure 0, we know that the set $B$ where $G \neq f$ has to have $B \subseteq A,$ and therefore be measurable with measure 0.
3. It's just a notational convention, Folland isn't super consistent. When the domain of integration is understood it is omitted, but $\int_{[a, b]} G \, dm$ would be the most verbose way of writing it if you wanted to eliminate any ambiguity. It's similar to how sometimes people write $\{x \mid x > 0\}.$ Technically, you should quantify this as $x \in \mathbb{R},$ but most people can infer the natural domain of $x$ from context.